# Yumex says "Authentication Failure" despite correct password, following large update -- Fedora 21

Tags: authentication

The title says it all, and I'm very confused. I can't find any other potential solutions to this issue... is anyone able to help me troubleshoot? I sure would apppreciate it...

Things I've tried:

Reinstalling yumex.

Running yum update again..

I was hoping to avoid doing a complete undo of the large update, because that seems like overkill... If I could just see *why* exactly authentication gets rejected, I feel like I might be able to uninstall one or two things and fix it...

UPDATE: Sorry guys, I'm retarded. I actually just needed to restart... Nothing told me that this would be necessary, so it slipped my mind that it might be. Thanks anyway if I wasted your time by making you think about this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem using korora. the only way I can acces yumex/ software install or any type of things like that are

@notroot $ su

@notroot $ password

@root $ yumex --root

and it would open

Comment: Thanks. I actually just needed to restart... Nothing told me that this would be necessary, so it slipped my mind that it might be. Thanks for the advice though -- I'll try that if I get stuck more-legitimately.